# How to get value from json array class

Tags: android, json

This is my code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
    try {
          JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
          Movie movie = new Movie();
          movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name")); //get json array name

           }               
            // adding movie to movies array
           movieList.add(movie);

         }
```

and I have `click listener` like this when list `onclick`:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {
        //update json array name to sqlite

           db.updateUser(XXXXXXXXXXXXXX); // this value i want get from json array movie.setTitle()

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);



            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

How can I get value from jsonarray and use it to onclicklistener?

Someone suggested using a bean class, but I'm not sure I understand how to do that..

Comment: tq @whereisSQL... my english so bad

Comment: where is the jsonArray is it in the same class?

Comment: no...its different class..

Comment: What value are you trying to get, in string float?

Comment: this one : movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Class which has the JsonArray

```
//create an ivar 
private static Movie myMovie // <- this is the value you want.
// then make a method
public static Moive getMovie(){return MyJSONArrayClass.myMovie}

 // modify your json Class to do this

for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
try {
      JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
      myMovie = new Movie();
      movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name")); //get json array name

       }               
        // adding movie to movies array
       movieList.add(movie);

     }


// then in the class with the onclick listener do

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {
    //update json array name to sqlite

       db.updateUser(XXXXXXXXXXXXXX); // this value i want get from json array movie.setTitle()

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);



Movie movie = MyJSONArrayClass.getMovie();
if(null != movie){
 // add your code here
 }

        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

you could also look at implementing a Singleton to serve the movie if you dont want to use statics

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet, the `response` variable references the JSON array, which you apparently received as the response from a network request. If you want the adapter to be able to continue to use that data after that code's method returns, you need to either retain a reference to the original data or you need to make a copy of the data (and either store it in memory for the lifetime of the adapter, or persist it somehow).

In your second code snippet, you only seem to need the movie titles. It so happens that in you first snippet, you are storing in `movieList` a list of `Movie` objects (each of which contains a movie title). So, if `movieList` is available for your second snippet to use, and if the `Movie` class provides a way to get the movie title (say, a `getTitle()` method), then you can do something like this in your second snippet to get the title of the clicked item:

```
String movieTitle = movieList.get(position).getTitle();
```

Note: The third parameter of `onItemClick()` is the position of the clicked item. Also, I assume that `movieList` has a type similar to `java.util.List<Movie>`.